# How to combine "find(id)" with leftJoin using eloquent

Tags: eloquent

I have 2 tables and would like to get from one table a row combined with some data from an other table.

I tried this one

```
$category = Category::find($id)
  ->leftJoin('photos', 'categories.cover_id', '=', 'photos.id')
  ->select('categories.*', 'photos.filename as cover')
  ->orderBy('sort', 'desc')
  ->get();
```

But I get only all data from Category and cover is "null".

What I'm doing wrong?

Gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilies for this, one be simple use DB query builder

```
$category = DB::table('categories')
  ->select('categories.*','photos.filename as cover')
  ->join('photos', 'photos.id', '=', 'categories.cover_id')
  ->where('categories.id',$id)->get();
```

second is,
I didnt understand why we need find() method we can use where condition, please check the below if it works for you

```
$category = Category::leftJoin('photos', 'categories.cover_id', '=', 'photos.id')
 ->select('categories.*', 'photos.filename as cover')
 ->orderBy('sort', 'desc')
 ->where('categories.id',$id)
 ->first();
```

one more way is

```
 $category = Category::leftJoin('photos', function($join) {
  $join->on('categories.cover_id', '=', 'photos.id');
 })->where('categories.id',$id)
->select('categories.*', 'photos.filename as cover')->first();
```